# How can I get current running context in Android?

Tags: android

I am trying to get current running context in android, I tried to use:

```
<application android:name="com.xyz.MyApplication">

</application>

public class MyApplication extends Application
{
    private static Context context;

    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();
        MyApplication.context = getApplicationContext();
    }

    public static Context getAppContext() 
    {
        return MyApplication.context;
    }
}
```

When I try to use `MyApplication.getAppContext()`, it gives me the error

> AndroidRuntime(14421): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application

Comment: You only set the context on the creation of the object, the static reference will return null if you haven't created the Application.

Comment: What do you mean by "they don't work correctly"? Some errormessage? Some unexpected behaviour that you could explain a little more? Then somebody can (and will) help you :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is working for me:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

private static Context mContext;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mContext = getApplicationContext();
}
public static Context getContext() {
    return mContext;
}
}
```

You will just need to call `MyApplication.getContext()` on any part of your app.

I'm assuming that the application XML tag is on the manifest.xml

```
<application
    android:name=".MyApplication"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
```

You don't need to create any instance of Application class, it will be created when you launch the app, before anything.

Comment: Thank you for reply, but still doesn't work they give me this error AndroidRuntime(14421): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application

Comment: Can you post your manifest.xml and review the package name and app class name?

Comment: but you made a memory leak with static Context ?!!

Comment: "Do not place Android context classes in static fields; this is a memory leak"

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the instance of Application class you can get it using,

```
MyApplication Obj = ((MyApplication )getApplicationContext());
```

If context then `getApplicationContext()` itself is enough.